# How to hide field from preprocess_node in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have simple problem. I've a field in my content type (header image) that must be printed in `page.tpl.php` (because of layout).

It works fine, i put some code in `theme_preprocess_page()` function to show that field in page.tpl.php

```
function theme_preprocess_page( &$variables, $hook )
{
    $node = menu_get_object();

    if( $node && $node->type == 'page' )
    {
        $view = node_view($node);
        $variables['headerimage'] = render($view['field_headerimage']);
    }
}
```

Now i am having problem hiding that field_headerimage from node view. It cannot be hidden from administration ui (content types -> manage display) because if i hide it from there, it will not be available in `theme_preprocess_page()` either.

So i try to hide that field from preprocess_node

```
function theme_preprocess_node( &$variables, $hook )
{
    if( $variables['page'] )
    {
        hide($variables['field_headerimage']);
        unset($variables['field_headerimage']);
        $variables['field_headerimage'] = NULL;
    }
}
```

I added every line of code i've tried in removing that from being displayed. What am i doing wrong? Or: How do you hide field from `theme_preprocess_node()`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In `hook_preprocess_node()` the content has already been built for the node object and dumped onto the `content` array; that's the array that will be converted to `$content` in the template file, and the one you need to remove the field display from:

```
if( $variables['page'] )
{
    hide($variables['content']['field_headerimage']);
    // ...
```

That should get rid of it no problem.

For the sake of completeness you could also do this easily in the node.tpl.php file too:

```
hide($content['field_headerimage']);
```

Or in [`hook_node_view()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7) in a custom module:

```
function MYMODULE_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  hide($node->content['field_headerimage']);
}
```